# Building PivotTable in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, data-manipulation

Here is my sample dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
Singer <- c("A","B","C","A","B","D")
Rank <- c(1,2,3,3,2,1)
data <- data_frame(Singer,Rank)
```

I would like to build a PivotTable to show how many times each singer are ranked 1,2,3. The row would be "1", "2" and "3", while the column should be "A", "B","C",and "D". The value would be the count of times.

I tried to use `summarise(group_by(kw,Singer.Vote),count=n())`. But it did not specify the singer.

Comment: what about singer `D`?

Comment: "D" should also be there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data %>% group_by(Singer, Rank) %>%
      summarize(times = n()) %>% spread(Singer, times)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
t(table(data))
```

which gives

```
    Singer
Rank A B C D
   1 1 0 0 1
   2 0 2 0 0
   3 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tabyl` from the janitor package.  The result is a data.frame and has `0` instead of `NA` where no combinations occur in the data.

```
library(janitor)

data %>%
  tabyl(Rank, Singer)

 Rank A B C D
    1 1 0 0 1
    2 0 2 0 0
    3 1 0 1 0
```